# Can Android 5's own device encryption mechanism be exploited by a malware?

Tags: encryption, malware, android, ransomware

My wife's phone can't boot into android and instead displays a message that encryption has failed and all data is lost. She did not start the encryption process by herself. Now my question is: **can android 5's own encryption mechanism be hijacked by ransomware?** (and not by means of some custom implementation manually encrypting contents of the photo folder for example)

Right now I'm trying to get to the data using TWRP, but I think to no avail as the internal storage folder is empty..

The android she was using was cyanogenmod 12.1 (android 5.1.1) for a galaxy s3 gt-i9300.

Why the encryption process itself failed, I don't know but it could be due to low battery as when finding it in this state it was at 3% or so. Though as I did encrypt my s3 manually and on purpose, encryption would only start with battery being at 100% and the phone being plugged in. Otherwise it would refuse if my memory serves me right.

Comment: Have you received any request for ransom? Modded/Custom OS's are not known for having stellar QA departments - my guess is that the encryption process was started by either an accident or bug.

Comment: No request is displayed. Since the encryption process itself failed the OS is in a broken state. Only option left is to factory reset it from there. So if it's ransomware then it in itself has failed, due to what I assume interruption by low battery. 
Regardin quality of the OS verison itself: yeah, it's the downside of custom ROMs, but still better than bloated stock android 4 on this old spare phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue was in a corrupted filesystem. Whether this is caused by a software or hardware issue I don't know. So when android booted it interpreted a corrupted ext4 data partition wrongly as being partially encrypted.

What I did to fix was following this comment on [reddit here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/84ubi2/encryption_unsuccessful_after_15120180305/e3pseio?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)

Quickly summarized:

boot into recovery, start adb from a linux system, pull the partition, fix it locally, push it back:

```
adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p12 data.img
sudo fsck.ext4 -y data.img
adb push data.img /dev/block/mmcblk0p12
```